# Statistic for assessing quality of dose response curve (fit with logistic regression)

Tags: r, logistic, quality-control, sigmoid-curve, dose-response

I want to assess the quality of a 4-parameter logistic regression fit on dose response data.

I am in the process of assessing the quality of some compound screening data. This is characterising the capacity of a drug to kill/slow growth of cells. A conventional method of analysing this data comes in the form of a 4 parameter logistic regression model fit (x = log10(drug concentration), y = cell response to drug).

Due to variations in curve fit quality, I want to use a statistic to quickly identify poor quality curves, as there are too many to inspect visually. In this case, I am simply interested in how well the logistic curve fits the data, I mean this in the sense akin to a high R-squared value for standard linear regression.

So far I’ve considered using R-squared in combination with AIC values. However, I wanted to sense check this and ask if there are any other statistics that would be good for this purpose? As there are setbacks to using just R2 such as the risk of models with non-random residual patterns, some other methods would be useful. Note there is no binary outcome in this data, simply response (y) and x (dose).

For reference, here is an example of a good curve:[image]

And an example of a bad curve:
[image]

In addition to the statistic I will set thresholds, such as y needs to pass 50% (i.e. 50% reduction in cells). But wanted another way to test this. For reference I have fit the curves using the drc R package, and have tried the `modelFit()` function but this did not seem to work well. Any code examples would be a bonus, but mainly looking for an answer on the methodology.